# Spring XD with Flo issue

Tags: spring, spring-xd

I currently have Flo installed with my Spring XD installation, however when I try to create a composed job the DSL fails to generate and I am not allowed to finish creating the job. Any ideas why this could be happening? I have spring xd 1.2.1 and have tried Flo 1.3.0 and 1.2.1

Comment: Do you have Basic Auth enabled? If so try disabling it and try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flo with batch support is only supported with Spring XD 1.3.x+.  You'll need to upgrade your XD installation to use it.